# How to choose which jupyter notebook to run?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed jupyter notebook for Python 3 (installed through pip) and for Python 2 (installed through anaconda stack which included scipy and scikit-learn and similar scientific tools).

When I run `jupyter notebook` in console it opens but I can choose only Python 2 kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal try inputting this:

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
```

and this:

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Then restart jupyter and anaconda and you should be able to select the other kernel version.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did it.